# Inputs, ouputs layers sklearn python

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I think I am missing somethings here but how does Mlp regressor from Sklearn compute or define the number of neurons in the inputs and outputs layers?

I could not find an explanation in the docs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sklean defines the input and output shapes within the `fit` method. 
In fact, every model in `sklearn` is a class that implements a method called `fit`.

Here's how the code looks like for the case of [sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neural_network.MLPRegressor.html) :

```
def fit(self, X, y):
    """Fit the model to data matrix X and target(s) y.
    Parameters
    ----------
    X : array-like or sparse matrix, shape (n_samples, n_features)
        The input data.
    y : array-like, shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_outputs)
        The target values (class labels in classification, real numbers in
        regression).
    Returns
    -------
    self : returns a trained MLP model.
    """
    return self._fit(X, y, incremental=False)
```

Check the code on [github](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/f3320a6f/sklearn/neural_network/multilayer_perceptron.py#L604) to understand more how everything works together.